# Joined table fields don't work in print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, attribute-joins

I am trying to use the attributes of the current atlas feature, which is from a joined table. In the expression builder it shows the correct value, but the result is blank when I actually try to insert it. Even using the attribute function, it doesn't let me pull back the data of those joined fields.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to flatten the data to the shapefile? I am using version 2.14

Comment: It was a bug, which will be fixed when 2.14.3 is released

Comment: Still not fixed in 2.14.3